# The requested URL XXXXX was not found on server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I installed the *lamp server* and tried to call the controller functions for running my web application in browser that is written in Codeigniter framework.

But after home page it always say `404 page not found on the server`.

I checked `.htaccess`, `routes`, `config` but still getting 404.

Also *it is properly working on the xamp server on windows*.

Screenshot:

[image]

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In Constants

```
define('SURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/warehouse/adminBAS/');
```

In config

```
$config['base_url'] = SURL;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Using OS: Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: try using index.php in URL, htaccess may not hide the index.php

Comment: This is Apache returned Error. Definitely It's Htaccess or Route problem. Post your config, routes and htaccess

Comment: On xamp it is working perfectly so why it requires here `index.php` ? Not argue but want to know reason...! thanks

Comment: Still not fixed...!

Comment: @NomanJaved show all the codes. htaccess routes and configs

Comment: @Spartan I edit the post with the code...! Have a look  .! Thanks

Comment: @NomanJaved is your mod_rewrite on for lamp server ?

Comment: Why you use `'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/warehouse/adminBAS/`. You cab set just static URL. Or try with virtual host like `site.dev`

Comment: This work fine when i upload the project on server I will not have to change the things again.